# Force Power Bi slicer to be single select

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power Bi dashboard that looks like this:

[image]

But I dont want all the rows of everyone's data to show up.  Ideally its single select only, these results look great when only Elizabeth is selected (not sure why screenshot looks like two people):

[image]

Because I want to stack quite a few other tables in the dashboard that are one row only, like so:

[image]

So my question is:  how can I force the name slicer on the left to ONLY allow one person to be selected, and never be 'not' selected where lots of people are involved?   Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a table and not a slicer. Tables will display everything you ask them to. If you switch it to a slicer, you can make it single select.

Comment: Silly question, can it still look the same though?  When I change it to slicer it drops the names and only says the record id, and they're little boxes.  I want the visual to be the exact same, but itll be a slicer.

Comment: It won't look the exact same. You can create a new column which concatenates your name and id so they're both shown and also have a list instead of a drop down. You can also play around with the colours but it won't look exactly the same.